# Class Not Found exception: STS

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, classnotfoundexception, classloader

Everything was working properly until i added a new java package to my project, when i run my application the stack trace shows `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, i had to reference another class library as i could not figure out how to compile fresh new classes using eclipse. I added an external folder to my build path to temporarily fix the problem but now i am faced with the same problem.

Stack Trace and web.xml are below:

My question is, how do you do compile a project to create new classes using eclipse?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bixin.dugsi.security.JpaRealm
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
... 38 more
```

WEB XML:

```
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Dugsi_Manager Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dugsi_Manager Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a `mvn clean` and a `mvn build` to clear the cache of all old classes and create new classes